# Why does is my code output returning as a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I did this code down below and i was expecting the output of the code to return as a tuple.

`li = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`

`(e, f, *g) = li`

`print(g)`

But the output was

`['c', 'd']`

What does "(e, f, *g) = li" actually mean and why did the code return as a list?

Comment: Because that is what [the specification in PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification) says: "A tuple (or list) on the left side of a simple assignment [...] may contain at most one expression prepended with a single asterisk (which is henceforth called a "starred" expression, while the other expressions in the list are called "mandatory"). This designates a subexpression that will be assigned a *list* of all items from the iterable being unpacked that are not assigned to any of the mandatory expressions, or an empty list if there are no such items."

Comment: @python_user While close enough, the linked answer doesn't mention why unpacking a tuple turns into a list.

Comment: @python_user Ah, I had overlooked that paragraph.